# How to get a keyname by its nested values in firebase?

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, livechat, firebasesimplelogin

[image]

My firebase is modeled this way. I want to write a query to get userID(simplelogin:1) where email is "test@gmail.com".

Here I want to get key: "simplelogin:1" by searching with it's email address:"test@gmail.com"

I am using firebase SDK for iOS. Can somebody suggest me a query for this? In Javascript or Objective-C

Comment: how to store data this way ??? please guide me

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After little messing around I found answer to the question:

```
Firebase *ref = [_rootReference childByAppendingPath:@"Users"];

[[[ref queryOrderedByChild:@"Email"]queryEqualToValue:@"test@gmail.com" ]
 observeEventType:FEventTypeChildAdded withBlock:^(FDataSnapshot *snapshot) {
     NSLog(@"%@ Key %@ Value", snapshot.key,snapshot.value);
 }];
```

There snaphot.key will be the value simplelogin:1 that I wanted.

Comment: Be sure to accept your answer once Stack Overflow allows this.

Answer (score 1):

I just want to add one thing on your code Prajeet. I think for the FEventType should be **FEventTypeValue**, because you're "observing" it once not every time when the child is added.

```
Firebase *ref = [_rootReference childByAppendingPath:@"Users"];

[[[ref queryOrderedByChild:@"Email"]queryEqualToValue:@"test@gmail.com" ]
 observeEventType:FEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FDataSnapshot *snapshot) {
     NSLog(@"%@ Key %@ Value", snapshot.key,snapshot.value);
 }];
```